# How to place a call in VB .Net for Windows phone 7?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-phone-7

I am new to WP7 programming. I am trying to initiate a call to a specific number from within a button in my application. I found example code on MSDN, but can't get it to work properly, and I think it is for the .net compact framework, not WP7.

All I want it to present a button to the user which, when clicked, calls a predefined number (after asking the user if it is ok to call).

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be better if you posted your solution as an *answer* to the question. Self-answering questions is actually very legitimate on Stack Overflow and this will make the solution more easily findable for other people with the same problem.

Comment: Agreed Konrad, and that is exactly what I was trying to do. However Stackoverflow restricts new users from self-answering for eight hours after the question was posted. I put the edit in to ensure that nobody wasted any time answering the question I had already started. Will enter the result as a self answer now.

Comment: Ah, didn’t know that. ;-) Here, have an upvote on the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sorted it.

Remarkably simple as it turns out - see below:

```
Dim callme As New Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask

callme.PhoneNumber = "numbertocall"
callme.Show()
```

Spent hours trying to sort this and it was so straightforward!